# Postgresql INNER JOIN with multiple conditons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on a query that is driving me nuts. I am trying to search a table by the values in a join table. Currently, the query is returning all results that have either of the specified ids. I would only like it to return records that only have both of the ids.

Here is my table setup

```
creat_table champions do |t|
  t.integer :id
end

create_table champions_champion_combinations do |t|
  t.integer :champion_id
  t.integer :champion_combination_id
end

create_table champion_combinations do |t|
  t.integer :id
end
```

Here is the query as I have it

```
SELECT 
  champion_combinations.* 
FROM champion_combinations
INNER JOIN champions_champion_combinations 
  ON champions_champion_combinations.champion_combination_id = champion_combinations.id
INNER JOIN champions
  ON champions.id = champions_champion_combinations.champion_id 
WHERE champions.id IN (1, 2)"
```

Generated from the RoR ActiveRecord query

```
ChampionCombination.joins(:champions).where(champions: {id:[1,2]})
```

So this returns all champion_combinations that have either champion ids 1 or 2 joined to it. What type of query do I need to write that only returns the combination with both ids 1 and 2 joined to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do 2 separate joins to `champions` table. One for first id, one for second id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interesting in pure SQL solution, then you can use [GROUP BY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) and [HAVING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING) clauses to achieve your goal. Here is the sql query:

```
SELECT cc.*
FROM champion_combinations AS cc
INNER JOIN champions_champion_combinations  AS ccc ON ccc.champion_combination_id = cc.id
WHERE ccc.champion_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY cc.id
HAVING array_agg(ccc.champion_id) @> ARRAY[1,2];
```

**PS** Thanks to @IgorRomanchenko for great suggestions.

Comment: You do not need `champions` table. You can safely use `ccc.champion_id` instead of `c.id`.

Comment: You shoud add additional condition `WHERE ccc.champion_id IN (1, 2)`. Otherwise postgres will be forced to do full scans and joins instead of indexed joins.

Comment: Again agreed:) Why I didn't think about it myself?:(

Comment: Thank you both, this works great and scales perfect for when I have more than 2 champion ids present. I prefer to use ActiveRecord but I couldn't find anything in the docs or SO that would let me generate this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not inner join problem. Inner join is working as expected. SQL query given above doing inner join of both the tables with "champion_combination", there is no restriction which says both ids has to be present. You should do is

ChampionCombination.joins(:champions).where(champions: {id:[1,2]}).where("champion_id is not null and compion_combination_id is not null")